# Mod_Rewrite for removing dashes and capitalizing following letter

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, yii

I am using The Yii framework and have Controllers and Actions that are multiple letters and camelcase. For example. UserStatusController and actions like RemoveStatus.

This makes for URLs that have to be www.website.com/userStatus/removeStatus. I would prefer to write them as www.website.com/user-status/remove-status and have mod_rewrite change them for me.

Can anyone give any advice on how to do this? I am not having any luck understanding mod rewrite rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do it this way. Works great.

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/404/hyphenation-of-routes-in-url-management/